# Which SQL table stores the FROM Email Addresses?

Tags: email, receipts

In Administer > Communication > FROM Email Addresses, I have changed the persons name associated with our donations@xyz.org email. However, receipts still have the old name associated with it. I am using a CiviRule to send a Message Template and the selection FROM Email shows the proper name, but it send the old name. Where in the database do I find this information so I can make sure it is properly cleaned up?

Comment: does changing the civirule to a different From address and then back again help?

Comment: otherwise see if you have the old value in the civirule_rule_action table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about how civirules stores it but the From addresses are just option values.

`select v.* from civicrm_option_value v inner join civicrm_option_group g on v.option_group_id=g.id and g.name='from_email_address';`

Comment: This got me what I needed. It appears that when you edit a FROM email address in the GUI, it changes the table civicrm_options_value > label but it also needs to change the > name column as well.

Comment: That sounds familiar - there might be an open labs ticket about that.

Comment: Ah I think this one: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2995

Comment: I am guessing tha tin the GUI I could have deleted the old entry and created a new one and solved the problem

Comment: It sounds like the email api extension used to use the internal machine name instead of label but that's now fixed in its latest code. The GUI should _not_ change the internal machine name once it is set. So yes creating a new one would temporarily fix it, but the extension shouldn't use name for display purposes.

Comment: So CiviRules should be using label instead of machine name? Rather than the GUI changing both label and name so they match?

Comment: If that is the case, how do you ever get rid of the "FIXME" in name of the civi default FROM address?

Comment: The email api extension (which civirules uses). It's fixed as of about a week ago via that ticket above, but you'd have to use the git master version since there isn't a new release yet.